# FFMpeg Mobile Async command execution failed with rc=1. in Android 11

Tags: android

I compress the videos using FFMPeg Mobile. That library is working Fine below android 10 but it gives an error on Android 11. Async command execution failed with rc=1. Thanks in advance.
Below is the Execution Command Code.

```
    String[] cmd = new String[5];
    cmd[0] = "-i";
    cmd[1] = uploadVideoModel.originalFilePath;
    cmd[2] = "-c:v";
    cmd[3] = "mpeg4";
    cmd[4] = uploadVideoModel.filePath;
    execFFmpegMobile(cmd);
```

And the Method to execute that command is

```
 private void execFFmpegMobile(String[] cmd) {
    try {
        long executionId = com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg.FFmpeg.executeAsync(cmd, (executionId1, rc) -> {
            if (rc == RETURN_CODE_SUCCESS) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Async command execution completed successfully.");
                constant.dismissProgressDialog();
                uploadMedia(uploadVideoList.get(0).getFilePath(), "Video", "video/*");
                File inputFile = new File(uploadVideoList.get(0).getFilePath());
                long inputVideoSize = inputFile.length();
                long fileSizeInKB = inputVideoSize / 1024;
                long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
                displayToast("Video Compressed Successfully.");
                Log.i(TAG, "addVideos: 0 Compressed File Size  " + fileSizeInMB + " :  File size Kb " + fileSizeInKB);
            } else if (rc == RETURN_CODE_CANCEL) {
                displayToast("Async command execution cancelled by user.");
                Log.i(TAG, "Async command execution cancelled by user.");
                constant.dismissProgressDialog();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "execFFmpegMobile: LogiNFo : "+Log.INFO +" ExcId "+executionId1);
                displayToast("Async command execution failed with rc=%d." + rc);
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Async command execution failed with rc=%d.", rc));
                constant.dismissProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

And the log is

> 2021-07-06 09:47:33.080 17845-17845/com.crymzee.mde_hub
> I/MissReportActivity: Async command execution failed with rc=1.

Answer (score 0):

Command is wrong. Please use this

```
String cmd = "-y -i " + oldPath + " -c:a copy -r 30 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28 -preset ultrafast " + newFile.getPath();
```